# How to read in lines until a certain line?

Tags: python, input

I want to make my code read in lines of number and stop reading in when three zeros are entered in.
Something like this:

```
1231343
13242134
.
.
(more lines of numbers)
.
.
0 0 0(end of the line)
```

I tried doing something like this, but obviously didn't work because line wasn't declared before the first line.

```
while line != "0 0 0":
    line = raw_input()
```

Am I even on the right track? Or do I have to use something else?

Comment: So why not just add a `line = None` just before the `while`?

Comment: your code works for me.

Comment: Oh, I guess I could've done that as well :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using infinite loop, and use [`break` statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) to get out of the loop if the condition met:

```
while True:
    line = raw_input()
    if line == '0 0 0':
        break
    # do something with `line`
```

Or using [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#iter) with sentinel value:

```
for line in iter(raw_input, '0 0 0'):  # will keep call `raw_input` until meet 0 0 0
    # do something with `line`
```

Comment: definitely `iter` is the perfect solution

Comment: @jamylak, `raw_input` removes a trailing newline.

Comment: @falsetru removed that comment, I misread the question which looked like it was reading from a file. yes `raw_input` clearly works fine

Comment: @jamylak, No problem. I will leave the comment because it seems like other also thought like that (according to other answets)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're reading from a file

```
for line in open('path to file'):
    if line.strip() == '0 0 0':
        break
```

Comment: IOW, `open('path to file')` should be `sys.stdin`.